# OpenApi Response with Dynamic Types in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, openapi

My NestJs server returns an indefinite list of stocks and their statuses:

```
"data": {
    "AAPL": {
        "status": 200,
        "tradable": true,
        "fractionable": true,
        "symbol": "AAPL"
    },
    "MCFT": {
        "status": 200,
        "tradable": true,
        "fractionable": true,
        "symbol": "MCFT"
    },
    ...
}
```

There are over 2 thousand stock tickers ("AAPL", "MCFT", etc). I understand that in OpenApi, you can define keys that are strings. Will I be able to define types like that in Nest? Is there a way to make the tickers key dynamic, so I do not have to keep updating the list of stocks?

Comment: Couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve. If you could elaborate on "Is there a way to make the tickers key dynamic" that would prove helpful. Also, are you referring to request or response body?

Comment: @IstiyakTailor Sorry this is my first stack overflow question.

What I had meant is for key to have the string type and take any string, and the value being the statuses shown in the question. I am referring to the response body.